# Is a binary quadratic form (over any field) that represents both $\pm 1$ necessarily hyperbolic?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, quadratic-forms

If a $2$-dimensional quadratic form over a field $\mathbb F$ that represents both $1$ and $-1$ necessarily hyperbolic?

Edit: Assume that $\text{char } \mathbb{F} \neq 2$.

Comment: What is your definition of hyperbolic? That there is a basis in which the matrix representation of the quadratic form is $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: @ Travis: Yes. or $XY$

Comment: Even with the modification, the answer is still no, see my revised answer.

Comment: @ Travis: Thanks! it is necessary and sufficient condition?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't know offhand. It is true that if $-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{F}$ then $v, w$ that satisfy $Q(v) = 1$ and $Q(w) = -1$, are linearly independent (since $Q(\lambda v) = \lambda^2 Q(v) = \lambda^2 \neq -1$, so $\lambda v \neq w$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$), so $(v, w)$ is a basis, and one can try to modify it so that it has the above form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no: In any field in which $-1$ is a square (e.g., for any field of characteristic $2$ or characteristic $p$, $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, or any field that contains $\mathbb{Q}[i]$), say, $-1 = f^2$, the quadratic form $Q((x, y)) := x^2$ satisfies $Q((1, 0)) = 1$ and $Q((f, 0)) = -1$ but again the quadratic form is degenerate.